# xml_grep to get related info in stanza

Tags: xml, bash, xpath

XML noob here.

If a stanza has <favorite>true</favorite> i want to only print the info in <path>XXXX</path>

I've been banging my head against the wall with xml_grep & xmllint trying to extract what i feel is a very simple amount of information.  Maybe these are the wrong tools?  would some python just be the easiest way to go about this?  i have no idea how to write that, though

```
<fileList>
    <file>
            <path>./filename.zip</path>
            <name>My Filename</name>
            <favorite>true</favorite>
            <lastaccessed>20210406T130359</lastaccessed>
    </file>
</fileList>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/docs.php) for that.

Here is snippet that gives only the required paths:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel --template --match "/fileList/file[favorite = 'true']" --value-of ./path --nl my_xml_file.xml
```

For example, if the contents of `my_xml_file.xml` are:

```xml
<fileList>
    <file>
            <path>./filename.zip</path>
            <name>My Filename</name>
            <favorite>true</favorite>
            <lastaccessed>20210406T130359</lastaccessed>
    </file>
    <file>
            <path>./filename2.zip</path>
            <name>My Filename</name>
            <favorite>false</favorite>
            <lastaccessed>20210406T130359</lastaccessed>
    </file>
</fileList>
```

This command returns:

```sh
./filename.zip
```

Comment: THAT'S PERFECT!  you've saved me hours of work!  thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) it's as simple as:

```
xidel -s "input.xml" -e '//file[favorite="true"]/path'
```